# .htaccess redirect php include requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm coding an application that has a folder called "core_elements" which contains all the core scripts of the application. I don't want to let hosts access to that folder so I made a get.php script in the root, that should access to them, (the hosts should send a request to the get.php script that includes the script inside core_elements).

The htaccess file redirect all the connection except for localhost into index.php.
The problem is that all the includes that get.php does are seen as they have been made by the external hosts.

I make you an example of what happens:

```
192.168.0.2 request get.php?executeScript=1
get.php include("core_elements/1.php");
redirected to index.php
```

How should it be:

```
192.168.0.2 request get.php?executeScript=1
get.php include("core_elements/1.php"); //htaccess see that the host is 127.0.0.1
"hello this is script 1.php"
```

The htaccess script inside core_elements is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /P_AC_2/area_clienti/core_elements

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```